# How to compare to assocative array values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i need your guide lines on how to differentiate between two associative array.
One array coming from Database, and other one was input data, i want to compare these two array, which are not matching to know which input was edited.

**Database**

```
$databaseValues = [
    [color] => [
        [0]=> red,
        [1]=> blue,
        [2]=> green
    ],
    [regional]=> [
        [0] => International
        [1] => Domestic
        [2] => International
    ]
];

$postValues = [
    [color] => [
        [0]=> red,
        [1]=> blue,
        [2]=> blue 
    ],
    [regional]=> [
        [0] => International
        [1] => Domestic
        [2] => Domestic
    ]
];
```

How would which  was changed by key and value, here you can clearly see post value changed green to blue

Comment: @Vinicius.Silva, did you read the question, it was associative array, the keys may change

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop through the post values, and on each iteration and compare that value to the corresponding value in the database.

Comment: Please aware answer which end with question. It should be comment.

Comment: [It's not hard to earn enough rep to make comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)